# BGL depth_first_search error with color map

Tags: c++, boost

Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to get started with BGL.  I'm experimenting with a depth first search:

```
boost::default_dfs_visitor vis;
boost::depth_first_search( graph, boost::visitor(vis) );
```

And I'm getting a sea of error messages regarding color maps:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:21,
                 from main.cc:6:
/usr/include/boost/property_map/shared_array_property_map.hpp: In member function 'T& boost::shared_array_property_map<T, IndexMap>::operator[](typename boost::property_traits<IndexMap>::key_type) const [with T = boost::default_color_type, IndexMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>]':
/usr/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:324:   instantiated from 'void boost::put(const boost::put_get_helper<Reference, PropertyMap>&, K, const V&) [with PropertyMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >, Reference = boost::default_color_type&, K = void*, V = boost::default_color_type]'
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:196:   instantiated from 'void boost::depth_first_search(const VertexListGraph&, DFSVisitor, ColorMap, typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor) [with VertexListGraph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, DFSVisitor = boost::dfs_visitor<boost::null_visitor>, ColorMap = boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >]'
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:295:   instantiated from 'void boost::depth_first_search(const VertexListGraph&, const boost::bgl_named_params<P, T, R>&) [with VertexListGraph = TreeGraph::graph_type, P = boost::dfs_visitor<boost::null_visitor>, T = boost::graph_visitor_t, R = boost::no_property]'
main.cc:272:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/property_map/shared_array_property_map.hpp:36: error: no match for 'operator[]' in '((const boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >*)this)->boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >::data[boost::get [with PropertyMap = boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>, Reference = const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, K = void*](((const boost::put_get_helper<const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >&)((const boost::put_get_helper<const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >*)(&((const boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >*)this)->boost::shared_array_property_map<boost::default_color_type, boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t> >::index))), ((void* const&)((void* const*)(& v))))]'
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_array.hpp:85: note: candidates are: T& boost::shared_array<T>::operator[](ptrdiff_t) const [with T = boost::default_color_type]
```

The documentation for depth_first_search says there is a default, and I've seen numerous examples that don't provide their own color map, so I'm not sure why there's a problem.

My graph type is:

```
typedef
  boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS,
  boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node>
  >
  graph_type;
```

I thought that maybe since I had a custom property map, perhaps that overwrites some color map default that depth_first_search needs, but I added:

```
boost::property<boost::vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type>
```

to the property list, and that didn't help either.

I tried using an external color_map for depth_first search, and that also didn't seem to help.

Any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t
```

This is the inportant part of the "sea of errors". Only `adjacency_list` that have `vecS` as the `VertexList` template parameter have a default internal `vertex_index` property and this property is used by the default color map (you are using `listS`). You have several alternatives:

- You can simply use `vecS` as the second parameter (if you don't need to modify the graph on the fly this is the easiest one).
- You can create an internal property and then make sure you initialize it and keep it up-to-date with your graph. For this you would need to define your `VertexProperty` as:

  ```
  boost::property<vertex_index_t, std::size_t, boost::property<boost::vertex_treegraphnode_t, TreeGraph::node>>
  ```

  and then:

  ```
  boost::property_map<graph_type,vertex_index_t>::type my_vertex_index_map=get(vertex_index,graph);
  std::size_t current_index=0;
  BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v,graph,graph_type)
      put(my_vertex_index_map,v,current_index++);
  ```
- You can create an external property, initialize it and keep it up-to-date, and then pass it to `depth_first_search` with a named parameter.

  ```
  typedef graph_traits<graph_type>::vertex_descriptor VertexDesc;
  typedef map<VertexDesc, size_t> VertexIndexMap;
  VertexIndexMap mapIndex;
  boost::associative_property_map<VertexIndexMap> my_vertex_index_map(mapIndex);
  std::size_t current_index=0;
  BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v,graph,graph_type)
      put(my_vertex_index_map,v,current_index++);
  ...
  boost::depth_first_search( graph, boost::visitor(vis).vertex_index_map(my_vertex_index_map);
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I don't think I can use vecS for the vertices, because the graph needs to be modified on the fly.

Comment: After my last post, I got the idea that perhaps the list was the problem, so I created an external property color map.  I did it the same way you created an external vertex_index_map, except I didn't initialize it to anything, and it seems to work.  Is it the case that the default color map will only work if there's a vertex_index_map, but if you provide you're own color map, it's unnecessary?  If so, is there a reason to prefer one over the other? Thanks.